# How do I eliminate duplicate values after pushing it inside javascript array

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I want to remove duplicate values for states in chartDataResults2 array:

```
for (i = 0; i < dataResults.length; i++) {
  function groupBy(array, f) {
    var groups = {};
    array.forEach(function(o) {
      var group = JSON.stringify(f(o));
      groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
      groups[group].push(o);
    });
    return Object.keys(groups).map(function(group) {
      return groups[group];
    })
  }

  var result = groupBy(dataResults, function(item) {
    return [item.State.Title];
  });

  States1 = result[i][0].State.Title;

  chartDataResults2.push({
    States: States1,
    Mineraltype: Mineraltype,
    CollectionAmount: CollectionAmount,
    Major: major,
    Minor: minor,
    CoalLignite: coal,
    balloonTextField: Mineraltype + ", Total Amount Collected:" + CollectionAmount,

  });
}
```

States has values (Andhra Pradesh,Gujarat,Gujarat).It should remove duplicates and just keep (Andhra Pradesh,Gujarat).

```
{States: "ANDHRA PRADESH", CollectionAmount: 187, Major: 187, Minor: 0, …}

{States: "GUJARAT",  CollectionAmount: 301, Major: 158, Minor: 90, …}

{States: "GUJARAT",  CollectionAmount: 0, Major: 0, Minor: 0, …}
```

Comment: how to get the states values

Comment: edited the code

Comment: Are you saying that within any one of the elements of `chartDataResults2` there could be an object with a `States` property that is an array that has duplicate values? Or that you don't want more than one `chartDataResults2` element with the same state?

Comment: use a `Set` instead of an array. `Set` does not store duplicates

Comment: @nnnnnn- I have edited to show you values in chartDataResults2

Comment: @CharlieMartin- Can you please show how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to group your data based on `States` value in an object. Then extract out all the values from the object.

```js
var data = [{States: "ANDHRA PRADESH", CollectionAmount: 187, Major: 187, Minor: 0},{States: "GUJARAT",  CollectionAmount: 301, Major: 158, Minor: 90},{States: "GUJARAT",  CollectionAmount: 0, Major: 0, Minor: 0}];
var result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,o) => {
  r[o.States] = r[o.States] || {...o};
  return r;
},{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json_all = [{States: "ANDHRA PRADESH", CollectionAmount: 187, Major: 187, Minor: 0, …},{States: "GUJARAT",  CollectionAmount: 301, Major: 158, Minor: 90, …},{States: "GUJARAT",  CollectionAmount: 0, Major: 0, Minor: 0, …}];
var arr = [],
    collection = [];

$.each(json_all, function (index, value) {
    if ($.inArray(value.id, arr) == -1) {
        arr.push(value.id);
        collection.push(value);
    }
});
```

try this way